# Why do I need offset operator?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu, gnu-assembler

Hi I had to write a AT&T x86 assembly to Intel assembly.

```
.section .data

str:    .ascii  "Hello world!\n"
    strlen = . - str

num:    .long   1337

.section .text

.global _start

_start:
    movl    $4, %eax
    movl    $1, %ebx
    movl    $str, %ecx
    movl    $strlen, %edx
    int $0x80

    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

That's AT&T

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .data

str:    .ascii  "Hello world!\n"
    strlen = . - str

num:    .long   1337

.section .text

.global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 4 
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, offset str
    mov edx, strlen
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1 
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

Why do I need this offset. I found it in another Stack Overflow question.

Compiling with:

as --32 -o hello.o helloworld-a.asm

ld -m elf_i386 -o hello hello.o

./hello

When I don't use it, I have no output on console.

Thanks :)

Comment: Because you want the address. Without that you get a memory reference in intel syntax mode.

Comment: Is it because of the label, because I saw also other code, where they define the string a different way like "hello db  "Hallo Welt!",0xa" and did not use it

Comment: That is not gnu assembler syntax though.

Comment: @JanWolfram: Presumably that was NASM syntax.  NASM is a different flavour of Intel syntax where a bare symbol name is always the address; you'd need `mov edx, [str]` in NASM to do a 4-byte load from the label address.  But GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` is MASM-like.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info for some about the differences.

Comment: PS: use a debugger and/or `strace` to see what args you're passing to system calls.  Even an AT&T syntax disassembler would have shown you the problem, since you know the difference between `mov $str, %ecx` and `mov str, %ecx`.